# Read applications in Folder in Java

Tags: java, macos, filenames

I saw in another question how to read files in a folder and in the answers I found some code and I modified the path and nothing else

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File folder = new File("/Applications/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

the problem was that it doesn't show applications in that folder. Is that due to security reasons or do I need to do something for it to show up?

PS: I'm on OSX

Comment: Have you tried specifying the entire filepath down to the Applications folder?

Comment: also worth noting: if you drag a file to the terminal window, you can get the correct file path

Comment: yes, the path is home folder then Applications aka: /Applications, right?
and I know it's the right folder because all the other things are showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X Applications are folders, not files.  They are special folders that end in a '.app' extension and contain a [special sub-directory structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html).  So by using `file.isFile()` you are effectively filtering the applications out.

Do this to list the applications:

```
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about that, thank you so much! It was making my angry why I wasn't getting it